# Can read return partial data when reading signalfd_siginfo structure?

Tags: c, linux, signals, epoll

The setup follows:

Some signals are blocked by program and report to `signalfd` file descriptor which is registered with `epoll` set.

When signal arrives I do this:

```
...
if(fd == sig_fd) { /* fd is a signal */
 rb = read(fd, &siginf, sizeof(siginf));
 assert(rb == sizeof(siginf))
...
```

The question:

Will my assert ever fail?

P.S: I've read through https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/signalfd.c source code.

As I understand the code copies data from the kernel in the multiples of a size of `signalfd_siginfo` structure. So, as it appears to me, it copies whole structs, and returns an error as some utility to the author.

But I am not sure where and under which circumstances the data gets passed to user. Can someone with enough experience give a definite answer?

**P.S**

And can read return zero(connection closed)? As above text mentions, I looked at source code, but I do not have that time to see all call structure.